# How to share IIS website with internal network

Tags: asp.net, web-services, networking, ip, exchange-server

my website is working good on my pc "win7" with domain "welcome.net" but I need to  browse this website from another computer connected with the same network.
antivirus and firewall is disabled.

My PC connect with exchange server. **How can i do it?**

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is known on the network as win7.welcome.net and the website is running on port 82 then your website would be available on http://win7.welcome.net:82

In some cases, if your homepage is not a standard one you would need to add it to the url :

http://win7.welcome.net:82/startPage.html

You can also use the IP address of the host computer to accomplish the same thing.

if your host computer is running on 72.123.21.13 for example then the website can be hit here :

http://72.123.21.13:82/startPage.html

Answer (score 1):

**Locally on your machine:**

You don't need to disable your virusscanner or your firewall.
Add a rule to the firewall using advanced settings, coose port, leave TCP checked and enter 80 in the specific local ports box. 
Allow the connection of course, make sure you check all 3 boxes Private, public and Domain. Enter a new like 'Local webserver'.

I assume you've put your website under the Default Website in IIS, check the bindings and make sure there is nothing in the hostname en the ip address shows *. If you have something there the website will only show if you type the name in host name into your browser and if you have an IP-address in the ip address box only names resolved to that address will work (ie 127.0.0.1 will never work from another machine).

Now open a command prompt on your PC and run

```
ipconfig /all
```

You will get a bunch of info but what you need is in the beginning:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : win7
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : welcome.net
```

I assume that is what you see..

On any PC in the network you can go to http://win7.welcome.net and see the website you've created.

I am not sure why you mention that you are connected to Exchange?